# About how to extract back EMF from SMO(sliding mode observer), maybe I need a doctor for this question

Tags: motor, motor-controller, synchronous-motor, pmsm

```
The equations of PMSM on alpha-beta frame(2 ﬁxed coordinate systems) are like this,
```

[image]

```
The sliding mode observer (SMO) is like this,
```

[image]

then we use Z to denote the sliding mode control terms,

[image]

when the observer has reached sliding mode surface, back EMF can be extract from Z by using a integrator or a LPF(low pass filter), and finally we can calculate theta e which is PMSM's electrical rotator angle.
[image]

but this whole thing is wrong!
the actual equation that calculates the theta e is,
[image]

so I want to ask where is my wrong?

Comment: p3 http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1199&context=electricalengineeringfacpub  maybe U need a doctor but I found this on Google

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 I dont know how to reply you by using this website, sorry. But I have read tons of related papers like this but none of them explain why we should use a LPF to extract back emf from Z, the sliding mode term, when the system reaches the sliding mode. I guess the LPF is a substitute for integrator.

Comment: The LPF achieves the required integration for pole time intervals when the motor pole frequency >> 0.35/ RC

Comment: and the induced current dI/dt=V/L

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75   then the LPF really is a substitute for integrator, thanks. but what's wrong with my formula deduction? the theta I deduced is different from any paper.

Comment: An attempt: I'm not aware of all the details of your question, but if you calculate the difference between your solution and the "real" one, will see that it's equal to \$\frac{\pi}{2}\$. Interesting is the fact that this value is the phase change caused by a first order filter for frequencies well above the frequency \$\omega_c\$. Does the real equation for \$\theta_e\$ consider a low pass filter?

Comment: @Dirceu Rodrigues Jr thank you but please scrutinize all my equations, and it won't take too long. As for the pi/2 , I know it's a little weird but all these calculations are based on theta e which is the rotator angle of PMSM.

Comment: Can anybody help? PLEASE